# How can I call getContentResolver in android?

Tags: android, android-context, android-contentresolver

I'm writing a library class to encapsulate some of my logic in my first Android app. One of the functions which I want to encapsulate is a function which queries the address book. As such, it needs a `ContentResolver`. I'm trying to figure out how to keep the library functions black-boxed... that is, to avoid having each `Activity` pass in its own context to get a `ContentResolver`.

Problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a `ContentResolver` from within my library function. I can't find an import that contains `getContentResolver`. Googling said to use `getContext` to get a `Context` on which to call `getContentResolver`, but I can't find an import containing `getContext` either. Next posts said to use `getSystemService` to get an object to call `getContext`. BUT - I can't find any import containing `getSystemService` either!

So I'm stuck wondering, how can I get a ContentResolver within an encapsulated library function, or am I pretty much stuck having every calling `Activity` pass in a reference to its own context?

My code is something basically like this:

```
public final class MyLibrary {
    private MyLibrary() {  }

    // take MyGroupItem as a class representing a projection
    // containing information from the address book groups
    public static ArrayList<MyGroupItem> getGroups() {
        // do work here that would access the contacts
        // thus requiring the ContentResolver
    }
}
```

getGroups is the method where I was looking to avoid having to pass in a `Context` or `ContentResolver` if I could, as I was hoping to have it cleanly black-boxed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have each library function call pass in a `ContentResolver`...  Or extend `Application` to keep hold of a context and access it statically.

Comment: What would be any other potential side-effects or "gotchas" of extending `Application`? Would there be anything I would need to clean up in a destructor method or anything, or ?

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to go this route. I have a class which `extends Application` and I have added the fully qualified class name as `android:name` in the app manifest file. So now in my library class, I am trying to call `getApplication()`, but it does not find it as a method, and gives me no refactoring hints of a needed import to add. How can I call `getApplication()` to get the app handle?

Answer (score 12):

You can use like this:

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver() with the proper context.
getActivity().getContentResolver() with the proper context.
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I wound up doing this, for any who may find this thread in the future:

I used sugarynugs' method of creating a class that `extends Application`, and then added the appropriate registration in the application manifest file. The code for my application class is then:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;

public class CoreLib extends Application {
    private static CoreLib me;

    public CoreLib() {
        me = this;
    }

    public static Context Context() {
        return me;
    }

    public static ContentResolver ContentResolver() {
        return me.getContentResolver();
    }
}
```

Then, to get a ContentResolver in my library class, my function code is such:

```
public static ArrayList<Group> getGroups(){
    ArrayList<Group> rv = new ArrayList<Group>();

    ContentResolver cr = CoreLib.ContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(
        Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI, 
        myProjection, 
        null, 
        null, 
        Groups.TITLE + " ASC"
    );

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(new Group(
            c.getInt(0), 
            c.getString(1), 
            c.getInt(2), 
            c.getInt(3), 
            c.getInt(4))
        );          
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Comment: How can you manage the permissions for this? If you want to restrict data exposure for some apps that use your library, how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

A bit hard without seeing more of how you are coding your library, but I don't see another option then to use the context, and so pass that when calling that class.

A 'random' class does not have the environment to get a contentresolver: you need a context.

Now it's not too strange to actually pass your (activity) context to your class. From http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

> On Android, a Context is used for many operations but mostly to load and
>   access resources. This is why all the
>   widgets receive a Context parameter in
>   their constructor. In a regular
>   Android application, you usually have
>   two kinds of Context, Activity and
>   Application. **It's usually the first
>   one that the developer passes to
>   classes and methods that need a
>   Context**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I updated with a small snippet of code showing what I was trying to do.

Comment: I think passing the context so you can use it to get the contentresolver is your sollution :)