# Is passing a ContentResolver risky?

Tags: android

I have 3 elements to my application:
1. UI (activity)
2. Model (class)
3. content provider - provides data from a database

In order for the model class to  access the data from the content provider I need the UI (activity) to pass it a ContentResolver - this way I can create a cursor in the model class:

```
        cursor = mContentResolver.query(
            MyobiliseData.CONTENT_URI_RUNSUMMARY,   // The content URI of the words table
            projection,                        // The columns to return for each row
            selectionClause,                    // Selection criteria
            selectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
            null);                        // The sort order for the returned rows
```

Is this acceptable practice, or is there a better way to call the content provider from a non-activity class?

thanks

anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common pattern to provide **context** from Activity to other classes, and then use context to obtain various objects via context getter methods, including **getContentResolver()**. See for example the answers to [How can I call getContentResolver in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895116/how-can-i-call-getcontentresolver-in-android)